# Ubuntu always installs Nvidia Driver instead of Tesla Driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I have a remote machine in a VM running Ubuntu 18.04 with a Tesla T4 installed. 
Now I would like to install the Tesla Driver. One the Nvidia page for the driver it says to install it like this:

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/158191/en-us

```
Once you accept the download please follow the steps listed below

i) `dpkg -i nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1804-440.64.00_1.0-1_amd64.deb’ for Ubuntu <-- this step is over after less than a second, which is suspicous
ii) `apt-get update`
iii) `apt-get install cuda-drivers`
iv) `reboot`
```

but if I do that Ubuntu just stubbornly installs the nvidia-driver-440 (which only works for graphics card, not Tesla Cards)
And so it gives me this error:

```
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.270863] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:02:02.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1eb8)
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.270863] NVRM: installed in this system is not supported by the
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.270863] NVRM: NVIDIA 440.64.00 driver release.
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.270863] NVRM: Please see 'Appendix A - Supported NVIDIA GPU Products'
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.270863] NVRM: in this release's README, available on the operating system
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 106
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.270863] NVRM: specific graphics driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.271384] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:02.0 failed with error -1
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.271428] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.271453] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.272297] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 241
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.321089] ioc0: LSI53C1030 B0: Capabilities={Initiator}
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.440342] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 241
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.442075] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 0000:02:02.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1eb8)
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.442075] NVRM: installed in this system is not supported by the
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.442075] NVRM: NVIDIA 440.64.00 driver release.
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.442075] NVRM: Please see 'Appendix A - Supported NVIDIA GPU Products'
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.442075] NVRM: in this release's README, available on the operating system
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.442075] NVRM: specific graphics driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.446243] nvidia: probe of 0000:02:02.0 failed with error -1
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.446920] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.447551] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA devices were initialized.
May 20 18:31:39 server1205 kernel: [    3.448407] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 241
```

Also confusingly its called nvidia-drvier in the download instead of tesla-driver
So how can I get the Nvidia Tesla driver installed on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

*nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1804-440.64.00_1.0-1_amd64.deb* is the name of the driver [provided by NVIDIA](http://us.download.nvidia.com/tesla/440.64.00/nvidia-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1804-440.64.00_1.0-1_amd64.deb) for the Tesla from that web page you provided, so it's not Ubuntu, it's NVIDIA causing the issue. Therefore, I suggest you [email](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/utils/login_form/redirect/ask) or [chat](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/chat/chat_launch/) with NVIDIA support